# URP water showing Differently in on Runtime

Tags: unity, c#, webgl, water, unity-urp

I am using [this water](https://github.com/aniruddhahar/URP-WaterShaders) for my URP webgl build but the problem is it is showing differently on the editor. When I  run the game then it showing correctly and when I build and run it in the browser then it showing like the editor. here is the snap
[image]

water required Depth texture and opaque texture settings on and i have made it. Just start getting this problem from last two days. previously it was running fine. Here is the inspector:
[image]

Here are my URP settings and Quality SEttings:

[image]

[image]

Comment: ”Under Player settings, select Linear color space for best color representation" Hmm... Is linear colour space / sRGB texture decoding supported on WebGL? I thought I recalled there being a limitation on that platform...

Comment: Linear Colour space is supported for Webgl 2.0, if the client don't have support for webgl 2 then the build will not run. Therefore gamma has selected